# How to make histograms in Python (scipy.stats) look as good as R?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

The following plot and its code were generated in R ([source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500744/how-could-i-designate-a-value-of-which-i-could-say-that-values-above-said-value)). How can I replicate this quality of a histogram in Python code using `scipy.stats`?

[image]

```
x = rgamma(1000, 3, .1)
hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="n = 1000: GAMMA(3, .1)")
curve(dgamma(x, 3, .1), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
abline(v = 55.81, lwd=2, col="blue")
abline(v = 53.2232, lwd=2, col="brown", lty="dotted")
```

The R plot above is alot better than Python's [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dgamma.html#scipy.stats.dgamma) histograms, one example shown below, but I know there are alternative plot libraries for python

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import dgamma
r = dgamma.rvs(1.1, size=1000)
ax.hist(r, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

Comment: I think `seaborn.histplot` only lets you superimpose the KDE curve (kernel density estimator), which is inaccurate compared to the actual parameter-fitted continuous distributions in `scipy.stats`. even the R code is not using KDE, it actually lays down `curve` according to the continuous distribution `dgamma`

Comment: @develarist are you able to include the source data that you use as a basis to generate the plot, ideally in the format of a `pandas` dataframe? Once you create a dataframe, you can paste the results here: with `df.to_dict()` assuming a dataframe called `df`.

Comment: the source of the R code created data as `x = rgamma(1000, 3, .1)`, while the data in the Python example is `r = dgamma.rvs(a, size=1000)`

Comment: @develarist I get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: see edit, `a=1.1`. the link for that example is linked in the question since showing all lines of code for the histogram that is not wanted doesn't help with finding an answer https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dgamma.html#scipy.stats.dgamma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `seaborn` `histplot` + `kdeplot` if you want the `kde` to be a different color. Regarding your comment and having the kde as a different color, I commented on this github here where [someone had a similar question](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2344) (I believe this is best way to do this in 2021). So, we are able to get very close to what you have posted with `R` with a little bit more code. There are many other parameters that you can pass directly to `sns.histplot` and `sns.kdeplot` or if the parameter doesn't exist you can add stuff with `plt` e.g. `plt.title('Seaborn Histplot Example')` or add stuff to axes with `ax.`.

```
from scipy.stats import dgamma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
r = dgamma.rvs(1.1, size=1000)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_context("talk")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,12))
sns.histplot(r, color='deepskyblue', stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(r, color='orange')
plt.title('Seaborn Histplot Example', size=24, fontweight='bold')
sns.histplot(r, color='deepskyblue', stat='density', edgecolor="black")
sns.kdeplot(r, color='orange')
plt.axvline(2.8, 0, 0.95, color='blue')
plt.axvline(2.4, 0, 0.95, color='brown', linestyle='--')
ax.tick_params(left=True, bottom=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `seaborn.distplot` will be deprecated it says so I'll try `seaborn.displot(kind='hist')`. u could too if you want

Comment: after trying your answer with `displot` instead of `distplot`, the color settings don't work since `hist_kws` and `kde_kws` are unrecognized. do you know how to set the black edge color and the blue bars in `displot`?

Comment: @develarist good timing. I just finished looking into this. You are right. We should be doing this the 2021 way. See updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I don't think R's `curve` function is quite the same as `sns.kdeplot(r, color='orange')` however. At least the documentation contains nothing about KDE. not saying you should altogether remove `kdeplot`, but it would be worth plotting it together with whatever *is* the python equivalent of R's `curve` function to see how `curve` and `kdeplot` compare. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/curve

Comment: @develarist `kdeplot` has a lot of options to adjust the curve with the parameters for `bw`, `bw_adjust`, `cut`, `clip`. Please see the "Notes" section here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html To be honest, at this level of detail with the curve, this is not my area of expertise and I am not a `R` user, so unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to compare.

Comment: @develarist however, this question is a really good one on this topic. The accepted answer explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596102/seaborn-selected-kde-bandwidth-is-0-cannot-estimate-density