# Add density curve to histogram python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram, density-plot

I have some data in a pandas dataframe and have plotted some histograms for each variable using the following code:

`df = df.hist(bins=30, figsize=(20, 20))`

and this results in the following output:

[image]

What I want to do is overlay a density curve onto each plot, however, I've been having some difficulty.  This is what I attempted to do using the seaborn and have used the following for loop to go through each column in the dataframe:

```
# loop through each column in the dataframe and create a density plot
for i in df.columns:
    plt.figure()             
    sns.distplot(df[i])
```

I've got this to work, however, it prints all of the columns vertically, plus, it also prints out lots of error code before the plots:

[image]

[image]

What I require is the plots printing in a grid (like the original histogram plot), without the error code.

Comment: Did you upgrade to the latest versions of matplotlib and seaborn?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932283/confusion-with-bandwidth-on-seaborns-kdeplot may shed some light on it as does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60596102/seaborn-selected-kde-bandwidth-is-0-cannot-estimate-density

Comment: I actually thought it might be something to do with stats models so called the stats models package from scipy.  I'll try setting the bandwidth manually.  Also, I'm pretty sure I have all the up-to-date versions of matplotlib and seaborn but will double check (I'm running everything through Anaconda).

Comment: Thanks to Paul Brennan, passing the following argument into the plot works: kde_kws={'bw':0.1}.

Comment: Although, further to my question above, I'm still not sure how to get each plot output into grid like my histogram output.